# How to change fill pattern (hatch) of the Confidence Interval in the Seaborn Lineplot function

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a simple lineplot with Seaborn using this code:

```
sns.lineplot(data=data, x='year', y='Value', color='#128094', linewidth=1, estimator=lambda x: x.sum() / 12)
```

Which produced this:

[image]

How could I change the pattern of the Confidence Interval so I get a hatched pattern such as '\\\'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `err_kws` from [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

  - **dict of keyword arguments**: *Additional paramters to control the aesthetics of the error bars. The kwargs are passed either to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between) or [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar), depending on `err_style`.*
  - Specify patterns as desired (e.g. `'\\\\'`) based on `{'/', '\\', '|', '-', '+', 'x', 'o', 'O', '.', '*'}` specified in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/shapes_and_collections/hatch_style_reference.html) (note that `\` is an [escape character](https://www.python-ds.com/python-3-escape-sequences) and needs to be written twice).

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
p = sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", err_kws={'linestyle': '--', 'hatch': '///', 'fc': 'none'}, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks, it worked nicely!

Comment: @FrankJimenez you're welcome. Glad that works for you.